# Google mobile ads RoboPod not compiling in build.gradle [using libgdx]

Tags: java, ios, gradle, build.gradle, robovm

This is the current error I am getting when trying to recompile build.gradle with the new dependency

> startup failed:
>     build file '/Users/GoodGameIndustries/Documents/uParty-App/build.gradle': 84: expecting '}', found ':' @ line 84, column 28.
>                compile “org.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:1.12.0”
>                                   ^

The weird part it I tried doing this with a different robopod (specifically the facebook one) and it worked completely fine with no errors. Can someone please help me out thanks in advance!

Here is the iOS dependency portion of my build.gradle file

```
project(":ios") {
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "robovm"

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
    compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"

    compile “org.robovm:robopods-google-mobile-ads-ios:1.12.0”
}
```

}

[Solved] I just started compiling with other dependencies and then switched back to this one and it compiled fine

Comment: As this seems to relate to a compile error you should provide the relevant source.

Comment: If this question is solved you should add an answer, so other can see what solved your issue.

Comment: If you actually used the quotes you used in this question, I think gradle would have complained about that. Otherwise, you probably just had to --refresh-dependencies.